# HTML injections in ASP.NET report viewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm currently working on a web application in ASP.NET that displays reports (created with SQL Sever BIDS) that grab data from a SQL Server database. Code-behind is in C#. I'm doing some security testing by sending HTML injections in the report parameters (just a couple tags will do it, e.g. `<i>text</i>`). After I click "View Report" it churns for about half a second and then throws the following error:

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.`

The call stack is all anonymous Javascript functions. I didn't write some of the underlying code in this project so I'm having trouble figuring out how to catch the error—*before* it gets sent to the server, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via adding the following Javascript code directly below (not inside) the ReportViewer tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input").blur(function () {
            ClientValidate(this);
        });
    </script>
```

where `ClientValidate()` is a function that strips HTML tags via regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code-behind looks like. Is it possible to intercept the PreRender event of ReportViewer and validate the report parameters?

```
    private void CheckReportParameters(LocalReport localReport)
    {
        foreach (ReportParameterInfo parameter in localReport.GetParameters())
        {
            string parameterValue;
            foreach (string value in parameter.Values)
            {
                // Take out offending characters or encode them
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems very promising. Unfortunately, the PreRender event is too late—the error is thrown before it is invoked. I also tried OnLoad, which was also too late, and OnInit, which was too early (the report hadn't been loaded yet).